# R How to apply the same function to differents .bil files

Tags: r, directory, lapply, rgdal

I am attempting to apply a data transformation to 400 different .bil datasets. I am familiar with the transformation I would like to do, but since I am relatively new to R, I am struggling to automate it.

Here is the transformation for 1 .bil dataset :

```
library(cruts)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(terra)
require(rgdal)

rdata <- "G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/CHIRPS brut/chirps-v2.0_201410/chirps-v2.0_201410.bil"
sdata <- readOGR("G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie","sub_pro_indon")

r <- raster(rdata)
r.vals <- extract(r, sdata)
r.mean <- unlist(lapply(r.vals, FUN=mean))
sdata@data <- data.frame(sdata@data, mean=r.mean)

# Write results
writeOGR(sdata,"G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/mean.shp", "mean", driver="ESRI Shapefile") 
write.csv2(sdata, "G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/mean.csv")
```

I tried to automate it via a function creation and the command lapply as :

```
wd <- "G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/CHIRPS brut"
setwd(wd)
files <- list.files(pattern = ".bil")


mean_calc <- function(X){
  r <- raster(rdata)
  r.vals <- extract(r, sdata)
  r.mean <- unlist(lapply(r.vals, FUN=mean))
  sdata@data <- data.frame(sdata@data, mean=r.mean)
  
  writeOGR(sdata,"G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/CHIRPS moyenne/201410pre_mean.shp", "201410pre_mean", driver="ESRI Shapefile") 
  write.csv2(sdata, "G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/CHIRPS moyenne/201410pre_mean.csv")
  
}


sdata <- readOGR("G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie","sub_pro_indon")

rdata <- "G:/Mon Drive/Doctorat/Données/Donnée spatiale indonésie/CHIRPS brut/chirps-v2.0_201410.bil"
lapply(rdata, mean_calc)
```

The issue here is that this process is not completely automated since I have to manually change the name of the new Shapefile and CSV files. What I am looking for is for the new dataset to take in his name a number from the name of the original dataset, but I am not sure how to do that. Can someone please provide assistance? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
files <- rep(f, 3)
sdata <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

Solution

```
x <- rast(files)
e <- extract(x, sdata, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

head(e)
#  ID elevation elevation elevation
#1  1  467.1052  467.1052  467.1052
#2  2  333.8629  333.8629  333.8629
#3  3  377.3712  377.3712  377.3712
#4  4  373.6000  373.6000  373.6000
#5  5  418.6490  418.6490  418.6490
#6  6  314.9969  314.9969  314.9969
```

Perhaps I missed something, but the general principle is that you should not need to use `lapply` since extract can work on all layers at once; it can also summarize.

To save the output to a csv and shapefile:

```
se <- extract(x, sdata[,3:4], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, bind=TRUE)
se
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 5  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : lux.shp
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_2   NAME_2 elevation elevation elevation
# type        : <num>    <chr>     <num>     <num>     <num>
# values      :     1 Clervaux     467.1     467.1     467.1
#                   2 Diekirch     333.9     333.9     333.9
#                   3  Redange     377.4     377.4     377.4

writeVector(se, "file.shp")
write.csv(se, "file.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

You should also avoid old packages like "rgdal", "sp" and "raster".

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm trying to apply your solution. I just have an issue on the loading data part. As each data set is different i can not use rep. How can I open all my dataset and put them in the same vector ? (a precision is that all the dataset have the same name except for some number which are increasing (ex : pre1 ; pre2 ; ... ; pre346)

Comment: You already have that in your code:  `f <- list.files(pattern = ".bil")`

Comment: Thank you so much I manage to do what I wanted ! I just add that for the export to .shp we must add `filetype="ESRI Shapefile"` for the .shp to be readable